# Jquery-ui sortable jumping around when new item is created

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've have a problem with jQuery UI Sortable.

If you run the demo, and click on `option 1`, then click add (it will add a new option. on the left side of each option, when you hover it, there will be an `s`. if you "grab" that you can drag the option around inside its parent container. All of this works fine.

But when you click "Add question", and then try to drag any of the options around they act really change, they kinda jumps around and i cant figure out why?

```
$(".sortAble").sortable({
  revert: true,
  items: ".row.none"
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.clear();
  $(document).on("focus", "input", function() {
    $(".conselect").removeClass("conselect");
    $(this).closest(".con").addClass("conselect");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".selector .item", function() {
    $(this).closest(".con").find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    if ($(this).closest(".selector").hasClass("active")) {
      var i = $(this).index();

      $(this).closest(".items").css("top", -(i * 35));
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      var selectedclass = $(this).find("span").attr("class");
      $(this).closest(".con").find(".icon").removeClass("choiceicon checkboxicon").addClass(selectedclass);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    $(this).closest(".selector").toggleClass("active");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".addq", function() {
    var newrow = $(this).closest(".row").prev(".sortAble").find(".row:last").clone();
    var i = $(this).closest(".row").index();
    newrow.find("input").val("").attr("placeholder", "Option " + i);
    newrow.appendTo($(this).closest(".row").prev(".sortAble"));
    // $(this).closest(".Question").find(".row:not(:first) input").each(function(i,x){
    //     $(this).attr("placeholder", "Option "+ (i + 1))
    // })
    checkRow($(this).closest(".Question"));
  });

  var newqrow = '<div class="Question con"> <div class="row"> <div class="input-field col s8"> <input id="" type="text" class="" placeholder="Question Title"> </div> <div class="settings input-field col s4"> <div class="selector"> <div class="items"> <div class="item selected"> <span class="radioicon"></span>Choice </div> <div class="item"> <span class="checkboxicon"></span>Checkbox </div> <div class="item"> Dropdown </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="sortAble"> <div class="row none"> <div class="col s12 qrow"> <div class="sort col s1"> <span class="fa fa-sort">s</span> </div> <div class="qoption col s11"> <div class="icon radioicon"> </div> <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Option 1"> <div class="deleteq"> <span class="fa fa-times"></span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="row q_T"> <div class="col s12 qrow"> <div class="addq col s12"> <span class="fa fa-plus-circle">add</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>';

  $(document).on("click", ".addqrow", function() {
    $(newqrow).insertAfter(".Question:last");
    runDrag();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".deleteq", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest(".Question");
    $(this).closest(".row").remove();
    checkRow(row);
  });

  function checkRow(row) {
    if (row.find(":not(.q_T) .qrow").length == 1) {
      row.find(".qrow .deleteq span").hide();
    } else {
      row.find(".qrow .deleteq span").show();
    }
    row.find(".row:not(:first) input").each(function(i, x) {
      $(this).attr("placeholder", "Option " + (i + 1))
    })
  }

  function runDrag() {
    $(".sortAble").sortable({
      revert: true,
      items: ".row.none"
    });
  }
  runDrag();

  $(".Tools").css("width", $(".Tools").width())
  moveScroller();



})

function moveScroller() {
  var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
  var $scroller = $('.Tools');

  var move = function() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
    if (st > ot) {
      $scroller.css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: "100px"
      });
    } else {
      $scroller.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: ""
      });
    }
  };
  $("#s4-workspace").scroll(move);
  move();
}
```

```css
.Create_Survey_Container .container {
  width: 400px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con .q_T {
  display: none;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con.conselect {
  border-left: 2px solid #4d90fe;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con.conselect .q_T {
  display: block;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con.conselect .qrow:hover .sort span {
  display: block;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Title .row {
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Title .row.none {
  padding: 0 00px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Title .row .input-field {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row {
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row.none {
  padding: 0 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .input-field {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .sort {
  text-align: center;
  width: 28px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .sort span {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  padding-top: 17px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption input {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .icon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .icon.radioicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Radio.png');
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .icon.checkboxicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Checkbox.png');
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .deleteq {
  text-align: right;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .deleteq span {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  padding-top: 17px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .addq {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .addq span {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .addq span:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools ul li {
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools ul li:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools ul li span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .CreateSurvey {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .CreateSurvey:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.selector {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  top: 10px;
}

.selector.active {
  overflow: visible;
}

.selector.active .items {
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.selector.active .items .item:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.selector .items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.selector .items .item {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selector .items .item .checkboxicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Checkbox_Checked.png');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 10px;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  float: left;
}

.selector .items .item .radioicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Radio_Checked.png');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 10px;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="Create_Survey_Container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="questions">
          <div class="Title con">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="Title" type="text" class="" placeholder="Title">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="Desciption" type="text" class="" placeholder="Description">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Question con">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s8">
                <input id="" type="text" class="" placeholder="Question Title">
              </div>
              <div class="settings input-field col s4">
                <div class="selector">
                  <div class="items">
                    <div class="item selected">
                      <span class="radioicon"></span>Choice
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <span class="checkboxicon"></span>Checkbox
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      Dropdown
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sortAble">
              <div class="row none">
                <div class="col s12 qrow">
                  <div class="sort col s1">
                    <span class="fa fa-sort">s</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="qoption col s11">
                    <div class="icon radioicon">

                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Option 1">
                    <div class="deleteq">
                      <span class="fa fa-times" style="display:none;"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row q_T">
              <div class="col s12 qrow">
                <div class="addq col s12">
                  <span class="fa fa-plus-circle">add</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Question con">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s8">
                <input id="" type="text" class="" placeholder="Question Title">
              </div>
              <div class="settings input-field col s4">
                <div class="selector">
                  <div class="items">
                    <div class="item selected">
                      <span class="radioicon"></span>Choice
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <span class="checkboxicon"></span>Checkbox
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      Dropdown
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sortAble">
              <div class="row none">
                <div class="col s12 qrow">
                  <div class="sort col s1">
                    <span class="fa fa-sort">s</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="qoption col s11">
                    <div class="icon radioicon">

                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Option 1">
                    <div class="deleteq">
                      <span class="fa fa-times" style="display:none;"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row q_T">
              <div class="col s12 qrow">
                <div class="addq col s12">
                  <span class="fa fa-plus-circle">add</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="scroller-anchor"></div>
        <div class="Tools">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="addqrow fa fa-plus-circle">Add Question</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="CreateSurvey">
          Create survey
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the major issue (I think) that made the rows to jump around.

I added the following:

```
.sortAble {
  position: relative;
}
```

Which make the scrolling to be relative to the direct parent of the sorted rows.

I also changed the `runDrag` function to this:

```
function runDrag( el ) {
    if( !el ) {
      el = $(".sortAble");
    }
    el.sortable({
      revert: true,
      items: "> .row.none"
    });
}
```

I added an optional parameter that I pass in the `.addq` event (`runDrag($(".Question:last .sortAble"));`) - This will make only the newly added element to be initiated with the scroll, and not all the existing elements.

Here is the full working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.clear();
  $(document).on("focus", "input", function() {
    $(".conselect").removeClass("conselect");
    $(this).closest(".con").addClass("conselect");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".selector .item", function() {
    $(this).closest(".con").find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    if ($(this).closest(".selector").hasClass("active")) {
      var i = $(this).index();

      $(this).closest(".items").css("top", -(i * 35));
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      var selectedclass = $(this).find("span").attr("class");
      $(this).closest(".con").find(".icon").removeClass("choiceicon checkboxicon").addClass(selectedclass);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    $(this).closest(".selector").toggleClass("active");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".addq", function() {
    var newrow = $(this).closest(".row").prev(".sortAble").find(".row:last").clone();
    var i = $(this).closest(".row").index();
    newrow.find("input").val("").attr("placeholder", "Option " + i);
    newrow.appendTo($(this).closest(".row").prev(".sortAble"));
    // $(this).closest(".Question").find(".row:not(:first) input").each(function(i,x){
    //     $(this).attr("placeholder", "Option "+ (i + 1))
    // })
    checkRow($(this).closest(".Question"));
  });

  var newqrow = '<div class="Question con"> <div class="row"> <div class="input-field col s8"> <input  type="text" class="" placeholder="Question Title"> </div> <div class="settings input-field col s4"> <div class="selector"> <div class="items"> <div class="item selected"> <span class="radioicon"></span>Choice </div> <div class="item"> <span class="checkboxicon"></span>Checkbox </div> <div class="item"> Dropdown </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="sortAble"> <div class="row none"> <div class="col s12 qrow"> <div class="sort col s1"> <span class="fa fa-sort">s</span> </div> <div class="qoption col s11"> <div class="icon radioicon"> </div> <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Option 1"> <div class="deleteq"> <span class="fa fa-times"></span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="row q_T"> <div class="col s12 qrow"> <div class="addq col s12"> <span class="fa fa-plus-circle">add</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>';

  $(document).on("click", ".addqrow", function() {
    $(newqrow).insertAfter(".Question:last");
    runDrag($(".Question:last .sortAble"));
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".deleteq", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest(".Question");
    $(this).closest(".row").remove();
    checkRow(row);
  });

  function checkRow(row) {
    if (row.find(":not(.q_T) .qrow").length == 1) {
      row.find(".qrow .deleteq span").hide();
    } else {
      row.find(".qrow .deleteq span").show();
    }
    row.find(".row:not(:first) input").each(function(i, x) {
      $(this).attr("placeholder", "Option " + (i + 1))
    })
  }

  function runDrag( el ) {
    if( !el ) {
      el = $(".sortAble");
    }
    el.sortable({
      revert: true,
      items: "> .row.none"
    });
  }
  runDrag();

  $(".Tools").css("width", $(".Tools").width())
  moveScroller();



})

function moveScroller() {
  var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
  var $scroller = $('.Tools');

  var move = function() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
    if (st > ot) {
      $scroller.css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: "100px"
      });
    } else {
      $scroller.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: ""
      });
    }
  };
  $("#s4-workspace").scroll(move);
  move();
}
```

```css
.Create_Survey_Container .container {
  width: 400px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con .q_T {
  display: none;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con.conselect {
  border-left: 2px solid #4d90fe;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con.conselect .q_T {
  display: block;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con.conselect .qrow:hover .sort span {
  display: block;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .con:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Title .row {
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Title .row.none {
  padding: 0 00px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Title .row .input-field {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row {
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row.none {
  padding: 0 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .input-field {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .sort {
  text-align: center;
  width: 28px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .sort span {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  padding-top: 17px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption input {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .icon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .icon.radioicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Radio.png');
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .icon.checkboxicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Checkbox.png');
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .deleteq {
  text-align: right;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .qoption .deleteq span {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  padding-top: 17px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .addq {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .addq span {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .questions .Question .row .qrow .addq span:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools ul li {
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools ul li:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .Tools ul li span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .CreateSurvey {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Create_Survey_Container .container .CreateSurvey:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.selector {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  top: 10px;
}

.selector.active {
  overflow: visible;
}

.selector.active .items {
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.selector.active .items .item:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.selector .items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.selector .items .item {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selector .items .item .checkboxicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Checkbox_Checked.png');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 10px;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  float: left;
}

.selector .items .item .radioicon {
  background-image: url('../img/Radio_Checked.png');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 10px;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  float: left;
}

.sortAble {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="Create_Survey_Container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="questions">
          <div class="Title con">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="Title" type="text" class="" placeholder="Title">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="Desciption" type="text" class="" placeholder="Description">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Question con">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s8">
                <input id="" type="text" class="" placeholder="Question Title">
              </div>
              <div class="settings input-field col s4">
                <div class="selector">
                  <div class="items">
                    <div class="item selected">
                      <span class="radioicon"></span>Choice
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <span class="checkboxicon"></span>Checkbox
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      Dropdown
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sortAble">
              <div class="row none">
                <div class="col s12 qrow">
                  <div class="sort col s1">
                    <span class="fa fa-sort">s</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="qoption col s11">
                    <div class="icon radioicon">

                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Option 1">
                    <div class="deleteq">
                      <span class="fa fa-times" style="display:none;"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row q_T">
              <div class="col s12 qrow">
                <div class="addq col s12">
                  <span class="fa fa-plus-circle">add</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Question con">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s8">
                <input id="" type="text" class="" placeholder="Question Title">
              </div>
              <div class="settings input-field col s4">
                <div class="selector">
                  <div class="items">
                    <div class="item selected">
                      <span class="radioicon"></span>Choice
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <span class="checkboxicon"></span>Checkbox
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      Dropdown
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sortAble">
              <div class="row none">
                <div class="col s12 qrow">
                  <div class="sort col s1">
                    <span class="fa fa-sort">s</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="qoption col s11">
                    <div class="icon radioicon">

                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Option 1">
                    <div class="deleteq">
                      <span class="fa fa-times" style="display:none;"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row q_T">
              <div class="col s12 qrow">
                <div class="addq col s12">
                  <span class="fa fa-plus-circle">add</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="scroller-anchor"></div>
        <div class="Tools">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="addqrow fa fa-plus-circle">Add Question</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="CreateSurvey">
          Create survey
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```